# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

I have an if condition to validate a user input with java script i had and error in this line

```
if(_("onee").checked = false && _("two").checked = false){
```

which say

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Comment: Note : its not a duplicate because the question don't match my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(_("onee").checked = false && _("two").checked = false){
```

change to

```
if(_("onee").checked == false && _("two").checked == false){...


= is for assignment
== is for value matching
=== is for value matching with type consideration
```

Answer (score 1):

In if condition you either use == to compare values or === to compare type and value both. In your case you just used one =. So the correct code would be

```
if(_("onee").checked == false && _("two").checked == false){
```

Comment: This is not true at all, in javascript not always == is used in if condition, === is used too for value and type match.

Comment: @MarcosGonzález But still it's true and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud compare with == or === operators not with single =. That is your error.